# Is it possible to remove automatically generated comments when generating Getters and Setters in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

Is it possible to change the settings in PhpStorm, so I get the function(s) without the comments? It's really unpleasant to remove all the comments when there are 20+ variables.

```
/**
* @return mixed
*/
public function getFoo() {
    return $this->foo;
}
```

Comment: if you have 20+ variables for a function, that means you are making something wrong.

Comment: Split your functions into smaller ones. I doubt your current functions are readable in their actual state if the have 20+ arguments.

Comment: Something defiantly wrong if you have 20+ variables look at breaking down the functionality in the function and break it into smaller reusable snippets so that the individual pieces of functionality can be reused elsewhere in your code base. Makes for cleaner, easier to read code.

Comment: Sorry for confusing question, the variables are in a class, and I wanted to  generate the get/set functions with Code->Generate without the default comments.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Perferences->Editor->File and Code Templates->Code(tab)->PHP Getter Method/PHP Setter Method

Comment: Thanks @omxv , that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Why it is  NOT RECOMMENDED?

Comment: I don't think it's NOT RECOMMENDED anymore, since we have typed variables and parameters.

Comment: Since we have typed properties, this is HIGHLY RECOMMENDED in 2021

Answer (score -1):

In 2023 it would be Editor -> Intentions -> PHP, and then uncheck

> "Generate PHPDoc"

Comment: This doesn't prevent "Getters and Setters..." from adding phpdocs